# k-Hyperbolic manifolds

Tags: complex-manifolds, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

A complex manifold $N$ is $k$-hyperbolic ($\dim N \geq k$) if any holomorphic map from $\mathbb C^k$ to $N$ has rank strictly less than k. Brody hyperbolic manifolds are $1$-hyperbolic for example. Can you give an example of complex $2$-hyperbolic manifold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-trivial example is $CP^3$ minus 5 hyperplanes
in general position. According to a theorem of Borel every holomorphic image of $C$ in this manifold
is contained in a plane. (And there are finitely many of these planes).
So every image of $C^2$ is also contained in a plane. And it is easy to see that the images can "fill" several planes.
So $k=2$ according to your definition.

Answer (score 0):

Take product of a hyperbolic manifold and a Riemann surface.

Comment: @Misha So, $\mathbb C \times (\mathbb C-\{0,1\})$ is 2-hyperbolic but not Brody hyperbolic?

Comment: Yes, of course. 